# Какое регулярное выражение заменяет все содержимое <> на placeholder

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо реализовать метод
`String` с параметрами `(String text, String placeholder)`,
который будет заменять в переданной строке `String text` всё содержимое скобок `<>` и сами скобки на переданную строку в `String placeholder`, используя регулярные выражения, и ещё нужно учесть вариант, когда необходимо заменить несколько замен `<>` в переданной строке.

Comment: `"s/<[^>]*./$PLACEHOLDER/g"` в POSIX basic regexps.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь в вопрос не в регулярном выражении, а в методе, который заменяет все найденные подстроки на заданную подстроку. Метод называется `replaceAll`.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compilte(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
String result = m.replaceAll(placeHolder);
```

Осталось понять, какое регулярное выражение соответствует угловым скобкам с любым содержимым внутри.

Простое предположение `<.*>` не сработает, поскольку шаблон `.*` съедает любые символы, в том числе и закрывающую угловую скобку. Поэтому так `<[^>]*>`, то есть открывающая угловая скобка, затем любые символы, за исключением закрывающей угловой скобки, затем закрывающая угловая скобка. Значит, первая строка будет:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compilte("<[^>]*>");
. . .
```